# 3D software like GeoGebra

Tags: geometry, math-software, education

Does it exist a free interactive geometry software, like GeoGebra, which works for 3D geometry? I would be able to draw spheres, great circles, and so on.

Comment: Perhaps you will get a better answer if you post at tex-latex.stackexchange.com

Comment: Well, I am searching for an interactive software. ArchimedesGeo3d (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes_Geo3D) seems quite good.

Answer (score 14):

GeoGebra 5.0 (with 3D) has been released:

https://www.geogebra.org/

Comment: Can this software draw 3D graphics with latitude and longitude?

Answer (score 9):

There will be a public preview of GeoGebra 3D soon. Keep an eye on the GeoGebra forums :)

Comment: Wow, very good!

Answer (score 4):

Geomview is fairly flexible, and allows you to work in Euclidean, spherical or hyperbolic geometry.  Depending on which operating system you use it might be easier or harder to get it installed.  It made it into the Ubuntu repositories recently, so if you're running Ubuntu it takes little effort to install.

That said, it's not the easiest software to *use* -- quite a ways away from the interface of GeoGebra. More often than not, if I need a high-quality rendered image of something 3-dimensional, I code a PovRay script and render it.

Blender is open-source and interactive.  It appears to be quite flexible -- it's used to produce models for 3d video games, for example.  I haven't really got comfortable using it, though.

Comment: I'm a POV-Ray fan too; this however requires you to specify positions as coordinates instead of being able to interactively move objects around. Some skill in coordinate geometry is really needed for its proper use.

Comment: True.  A 3d package of the quality of GeoGebra would be most welcome.

Comment: For the unfamiliar: http://www.blender.org/ . There's a portable version if you don't want to bother with installing and you just want to try it out: http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/blender_portable

Answer (score 2):

You can try pgftikz http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/

Comment: It is a very good software! But it isn't interactive. I would like to construct my figures and manipulate it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can, to a limited extent, use [Google Sketchup](http://sketchup.google.com/), but that's not really the same.

[Cabri3D](http://www.cabri.com/cabri-3d.html) is probably the most like what you want, but it's commercial.  [Autograph](http://www.autograph-math.com/), also commercial, may do some of that kind of stuff, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @JM: oops.  I didn't mean [GrafEq](http://www.peda.com/grafeq/), which I really like but as you said doesn't do anything like this; I meant Autograph.

Comment: Isaac: FWIW, the only reason I remember is that I used it incessantly to draw curves, pre-*Mathematica*. Also because the guy who wrote it has a "self-referential" equation named after him. :)

Answer (score 2):

here is a complete list of softwares:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_interactive_geometry_software

Answer (score 2):

I developed a free 3d drawing program that runs in modern browsers (HTML5, based on [Three.js](https://threejs.org/)). The English version is called [Geoservant 3D](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/en), the original German version is called [Geoknecht 3D](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/de).

> I would be able to draw spheres, great circles, and so on.

You can easily draw:

> cube, cuboid, cylinder, line, line segment, plane, point, polygon, quadrangle (square), sphere, text, triangle, vector.

Rotation is available for: Cuboid, cube, text, cylinder as well.

After you specified some 3d shapes you can also animate their properties by changing the number values. See description on page how to change values: holding down ALT key and using cursor keys. Also have a look at the [gallery](https://www.matheretter.de/geoservant/en#gallery) on the page to see what things you can achieve with this program. It also calculates basic values of the 3d objects.

Currently I am using it a lot to solve vector and plane equations. By the visualization I can check if the result is correct. That is one use case, and it is super helpful for me.

Hope that helps you too.

Example:

[image: 3d-coordinates of a cube with space diagonal and face diagonal]

If you search for a program for 2D drawings, you could use the new [Geodrafter 2D](https://www.matheretter.de/calc/geodrafter).

Update: Geoservant is now available in German, English, Chinese, and Swedish.

Answer (score 0):

Try kd3-surf if you haven't yet found it at http://k3dsurf.sourceforge.net/

Free software and small file size, easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a mac, theres a plotting software build in.
Go to Applications / Utilities / Grapher.
It's easy and powerful, can plot 2D and 3D graphs.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a programmer, you might have some luck with [Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) and the [ezmesh](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/ezmesh.html) function

A MATLAB tutorial is available [here](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~jmr/241/lines_planes.html).  Usually Octave functions behave exactly like MATLAB ones, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [DMelt program](http://jwork.org/dmelt/). It is free.  You can draw 3D functions, parametric functions in 3D. The canvas is called HPlot3D.
Look at the at the example galley with math plots.

Comment: -1: The question is not asking for plotting software.

Answer (score 0):

FEOGWEBRA 3D IS TOP NOCH, BUT HERE ARE SOME ALTERNATVES:

Archimedes Geo3Dhttp://archimedesgeo3d.weebly.com/

THE CLASSIC CABRI 3D: https://cabri.com/en/enterprise/cabri-3d/index.html
CALQUES 3D> http://www.calques3d.org/( YHE ONLY ONE THAT OFFERS 3D LOCI